# "Is someone covering/going to cover this event?"

Tags: word-choice, future, present-tense, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

Which one of the following is better or more correct?

> Is someone **covering** this event?

> Is someone **going to cover** this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, but mean different things.

> Is someone covering this event?

asks if someone is currently responsible for it.

> Is someone going to cover this event?

implies that either nobody is (yet) responsible for it, or the asker is unaware of someone being assigned to it.

Comment: They don't *have* to mean different things. A newspaper editor could use either version in his "team meeting" to ask whether anyone is currently assigned to cover the event (which could be due to happen at any time in the future).

Comment: That's true. The exact detailed differences between the two, I think, is rather vague, and in most cases, either would be correct/understood. I tried to highlight in my answer the situations where they *do* in fact have different meanings

Comment: Precisely. There are definitely contexts where the two have exactly the same meaning. If the event is already ongoing the second can't be used at all, but offhand I can't think of any other context where they are both valid and unambiguously have different meanings. Unless you vary the inflection, which is kinda cheating.

Comment: Fortunately, OP is only asking about correctness, which is a far simpler issue in this case.